# How to add new aggregation to xAxis by using highcharts?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, elasticsearch, highcharts

I just started to use highcharts-vue. I can basically create most of the charts, but I want to add new aggregation on my column chart's xAxis like ElasticSearch.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-col md="12">
      <highcharts :options="chartOptions"></highcharts>
    </b-col>
    <b-col md="12" style="margin-top: 40px">
      <highcharts :options="pieChartOptions"></highcharts>

    </b-col>

  </div>

</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import {mapActions} from "vuex";
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import {Chart} from 'highcharts-vue'
import DashboardTable from "../../components/DashboardTable/DashboardTable";
import Widget from '@/components/Widget/Widget';

export default {
  name:"TestChart",
  components: {
    DashboardTable, Widget,
    highcharts: Chart
  },
  data(){
    return{
      chartOptions:{
        chart:{
          type: 'column'
        },
        title:{
          text: 'Deneme Bar Chart'
        },
        xAxis:{
          categories:['bengu', 'kursat', 'kenan', 'elif'],
        },
        yAxis:{
          title:{
            text: 'İçilen Kahve'
          }
        },
        series:[{
            name: 'Kahve',
            data: [2,8,5,7]
        }]
      },
      pieChartOptions:{
        chart:{
          type:'pie'
        },
        title:{
          text:'İçilen Kahve'
        },
        series:[{
          name:'Coffee',
          data:[{
            name: 'Espresso',
            y: 10.10
          },
            {
              name: 'Americano',
              y: 30.41
            },
            {
              name: 'Cafe Latte',
              y:35.90
            },
            {
              name: 'Filter Coffee',
              y: 20.59
            },
            {
              name: 'Turkish Coffee',
              y: 3.0
          }]
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}

</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Here is the screenshot my chart: [image]

And ElasticSearch chart: [image]

As you can see I have one data for my xAxis which is categories, but I want to add new aggregation. I showed the number of drinking coffee. Can I add a types of drinking coffee for my all categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stacking gives you the feature to glue another posts, simply add new series with a type of drinking coffee.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stacking: 'normal'
    }
},
```

API References: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.stacking